# Is this question on-topic?

Tags: support

Is it possible to get statistics about how many % Java installations are what version e.g. in India, how many users run Java 5, Java 6, Java 7, Java 8, Java 9, Java 10 respectively?

The background is that I speak with management who argue that newer must be better, therefore we should upgrade to Java 9 and Java 10. I answer that many users still run Java 6 - Java 7 for example smartphones that are a few years old.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No, this is not on topic for The Workplace

This isn't an issue on navigating the workplace, it's looking for statistical data for a given platform.  It wouldn't be on topic on any of the stacks here as far as I'm aware.

There may well be some statistical information available from Oracle themselves on it, but it's definitely not a question that we would (or could) answer in The Workplace.

Comment: This one IMO is way off topic.

Answer (score 4):

The question as you framed it is not on-topic for the reason Jane mentioned. However, your actual goal of how to convince or negotiate with management to support customers using older systems is definitely on-topic.

The solution you are thinking of is a good one indeed, but I am sure our community can offer other approaches, some of which you would hopefully find useful. I would request you to consider posting the question without specifically asking for statistical data. Let me/us know if you need help framing the question.